# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' maven dependency

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

My pom.xml contains dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

but still getting error:

> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>
> INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
>
> WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

Comment: You have added `mariaDb` but error shows mysql?

Comment: You should probably change your configuration as well.   ```Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");``` line like this is what you should look for. EDIT: just noticed you're using hibernate. Look into your configuration properties.